# Discord - Chat to a bot on another server

Tags: bots, discord

Basically there is a server with a BOT, i want to make my BOT from my server send a PM to the other BOT, the other BOT is not on my server, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for two main reasons.

1. It's explicitly blocked by Discord. You'd get the following error:
   `The server responded with error 50007: Cannot send messages to this user`
2. Bots can only send a PM to a user if they share a server with the user. So while the other bot does not need to be in your server, your bot will need to be in at least one server with the other bot.
   *Of course, point 1 makes this a moot point anyway*